# Fusion 360 starts, but no window appears

Tags: windows, windows-11

I installed Fusion 360 on Windows 11, the installation finishes correctly and no errors but when I try to launch Fusion 360 the process is started (I see this in the task manager) but there is no window!

I don't understand I deleted the AppData files and tried to do a clean uninstall but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

[image: my task manager when i launch fusion 360]

[image: the proof of a correct installation of fusion 360]

Comment: Which AppData files have you deleted? From exactly which folder?

Comment: I have delete local autodesk directorie and roaming autodesk directorie